# why safari is not working with css . even css class name is displaying?

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, safari

I have following css rules for safari

```
.userresult {
  border-right: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212121;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline-block;
}

var userresult = quizcss.@com.quiz.client.QuizResourceBundle.QuizCSSResource::userresult()();
var WrongAnswer=document.createElement("div");
WrongAnswer.className=userresult;
WrongAnswer.innerHTML="Wrong<br>Answer";
```

during inspect element css name shown but rules not. when i clicked on css class name. all effects are displaying. is there any rule safari..

Comment: I don't have/use safari, but it sounds like either, (A) your rules are being overwritten somewhere else in your styling sheet(s) or (B) you've managed to 'minimise' your class names (much like expand/minimise to save room on screen). But with this little info, it's quite hard to choose which. Could you possibly expand on this?

Comment: I checked it out no rules were overwritten, and also minimize class name but no effect ...

Comment: *Could you possibly expand on this?* - Please add details into your question.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle/jsbin demostrating your problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
WrongAnswer.className=userresult;
```

should be string

```
WrongAnswer.className="userresult";
```

---

EDIT

Or `userresul` value should be exactly `userresult`, but now I don't know what is the value of it.

Comment: I am using css ResourceBundle. in this case userresult in a variable

Comment: If you inspect this element, what does it look like? Does it have class attribute `class="userresult"`?

Comment: during inspect element css name shown but rules not. when i clicked on css class name. all effects are displaying. is there any rule for safari..